# How to use Member of in Oracle SQL and why does my implementation throw wrong number of types of arguments

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, database-trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MYTRIGGER 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON MAP_CALCULATION_SHOP_LIMITS
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    TYPE table_is_delete IS TABLE OF map_calculation.is_delete%TYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
    TYPE table_is_editable IS TABLE OF map_calculation.is_editable%TYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
    var_table_is_delete table_is_delete;
    var_table_is_editable table_is_editable;
BEGIN
    SELECT IS_DELETE, IS_EDITABLE 
    BULK COLLECT INTO var_table_is_delete, var_table_is_editable
    FROM MAP_CALCULATION MC 
    INNER JOIN map_calculation_group MG ON MC.ID_CALC = MG.ID_CALC 
    WHERE MG.ID_CALC = MC.ID_CALC 
    AND (mg.id_group = :old.id_group OR mg.id_group = :new.id_group);

    IF (UPDATING OR INSERTING) 
    AND 'F' MEMBER OF var_table_is_editable THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20004, '.......' );   
    ELSIF DELETING 
    AND ('T' MEMBER OF (var_table_is_delete)) THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20005, '...............' );
  END IF;
END;
/
```

This Select returns two rows always. Each row has 2 fields. I divide them into 2 collections by field. All fields are of Varchar2(1Byte) type. Where is it wrong? Maybe `index by` is wrong? Though when I tried to change it it raised even more errors.

Answer (score 0):

The MEMBER OF is used in a nested table since yours is associative array you have to use like the below

```
 IF var_table_is_editable.COUNT > 0 
 THEN  
 FOR i in var_table_is_editable.FIRST..var_table_is_editable.LAST
 LOOP
 IF (UPDATING OR INSERTING)
 AND  var_table_is_editable(i)='F'
 THEN
 RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20004, '.......' ); 
 ELSIF DELETING AND var_table_is_delete(i)='T' THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20005, '...............' );
 END IF;
 END LOOP;
 END IF;
```

OR you can do something like the below without using collections

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MYTRIGGER 
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON MAP_CALCULATION_SHOP_LIMITS
    FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
          var_is_delete NUMBER;
          var_is_editable NUMBER;

    BEGIN
        SELECT COUNT(1) 
        INTO var_is_delete
        FROM MAP_CALCULATION MC 
        INNER JOIN map_calculation_group MG ON MC.ID_CALC = MG.ID_CALC 
        WHERE MG.ID_CALC = MC.ID_CALC 
        AND (mg.id_group = :old.id_group OR mg.id_group = :new.id_group)
        AND IS_DELETE='T';

        SELECT COUNT(1) 
        INTO var_is_editable
        FROM MAP_CALCULATION MC 
        INNER JOIN map_calculation_group MG ON MC.ID_CALC = MG.ID_CALC 
        WHERE MG.ID_CALC = MC.ID_CALC 
        AND (mg.id_group = :old.id_group OR mg.id_group = :new.id_group)
        AND is_editable='F';



        IF (UPDATING OR INSERTING) 
        AND  var_is_editable > 0 THEN
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20004, '.......' );   
        ELSIF DELETING 
        AND var_is_delete > 0 THEN
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20005, '...............' );
      END IF;
    END;
```

Comment: Maybe I don't need index by at all?

Comment: you need it if there are more than one row